Motivation behind using term “manifold” for manifolds?
Why Riemann picked word “manifold” for his work in that area?
I read somewhere that it might have to do with geometry in more that 3 dimensions, since three numbers (x,y,z) are enough to give coordinates to a point in 3D thus this object (x,y,z) is like a 3-tuple or threefold number. A point in 2D is a twofold number etc.
Any geometrical object that you can parameterize with coordinates is a manifold, right? If so, the tuples (x,y,z, …) are of principal importance to this field of study, thus usage of the term manifold to designate the most vital thing in the subject.
Please, correct my reasoning if you can. Thanks.
P.S. my math level is super elementary :) don’t judge.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_manifolds_and_varieties#:~:text=Bernhard%20Riemann%20was%20the%20first,Clifford%20translated%20as%20%22manifoldness%22. and https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/was-the-term-manifold-or-its-german-equivalent-chosen-with-the-verb-to-fold

Summarizing Moishe's excellent links in the comments, the basic motivation appears to be simpler: just that a manifold has many points. The original term Riemann uses he even applies to sets, not just to manifolds in the modern sense. Quoting from the Wikipedia article, emphasis mine:

Bernhard Riemann was the first to do extensive work generalizing the idea of a surface to higher dimensions. The name manifold comes from Riemann's original German term, Mannigfaltigkeit, which William Kingdon Clifford translated as "manifoldness". In his Göttingen inaugural lecture, Riemann described the set of all possible values of a variable with certain constraints as a Mannigfaltigkeit, because the variable can have many values. He distinguishes between stetige Mannigfaltigkeit and diskrete Mannigfaltigkeit (continuous manifoldness and discontinuous manifoldness), depending on whether the value changes continuously or not. As continuous examples, Riemann refers to not only colors and the locations of objects in space, but also the possible shapes of a spatial figure. Using induction, Riemann constructs an n-fach ausgedehnte Mannigfaltigkeit (n times extended manifoldness or n-dimensional manifoldness) as a continuous stack of (n−1) dimensional manifoldnesses. Riemann's intuitive notion of a Mannigfaltigkeit evolved into what is today formalized as a manifold. Riemannian manifolds and Riemann surfaces are named after Bernhard Riemann.

And quoting from Conifold's HSM answer, emphasis mine:

Riemann himself in his lecture uses Mannigfaltigkeit as almost synonymous with "magnitude", saying that he set himself "the task of constructing the notion of a multiply extended magnitude", and invokes different intuitions when first using the word, Mannigfaltigkeit can equally be discrete: "according as there exists... a continuous path from one to another or not, they form a continuous or discrete manifoldness; the individual specialisations are called in the first case points, in the second case elements". He is also quite clear on his influences: "besides some very short hints on the matter given by Privy Councillor Gauss in his second memoir on Biquadratic Residues, in the Gottingen Gelehrte Anzeige, and in his Jubileebook, and some philosophical researches of Herbart, I could make use of no previous labours". Herbart is a German philosopher who clarified and popularized Kant's philosophy of space, he also influenced Grassman and his "science of magnitude".

I might render "manifold" in slightly more transparent English as "manyness".

Why invent the word "manyness" when we have an existing word "plurality" for that concept?

I want to emphasize the etymological connection. "Mani" and "many" have the same root.

That doesn't really help. "Manifold" is an English adjective of very long standing that means "many and varied". It has later attained a sense as a noun with a meaning that should really be "manifoldness" to tally with Riemann's "mannigfaltigkeit".
